# Unite multiple numeric columns if their names are sharing last 3 characters

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

I have a dataset with 150 columns, where columns are named as Qa101 to Qa150, Qb101 to Qb150, and Qc101 to Qc150. The plan is to unite columns where last three characters of the name, e.g., 101, are shared, and only have one column for each 3 with sharing last three characters, e.g., Qa101, Qb101, and Qc101, should unite into Q101. The columns of are numeric value, and it is certain that only one of these three columns with sharing last three characters are holding a value and the two others are NAs, for example Qa101 is holding a value, Qb101 and Qc101 are NAs, and so on.
I was hoping to find a `tidyverse` solution, but at this stage would settle for anything.

I have already tried different unsuccessful ways using dplyr functions such as:

```
data.test <- data %>%
  mutate(across(where(~ str_match(., start = -3))),
         unite(remove = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE), .keep = "none")
```

but it is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described:

> It is certain that only one of these three columns with sharing last three characters (e.g. `Qa101`, `Qb101`, `Qc101`) are holding a value and the two others are NAs.

I create a minimal example dataset:

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- as.data.frame(
  matrix(t(replicate(9, sample(c(sample(1:10, 1), NA, NA)))), 3, 9,
         dimnames = list(NULL, paste0(rep(c("Qa", "Qb", "Qc"), each = 3), 101:103)))
)

#   Qa101 Qa102 Qa103 Qb101 Qb102 Qb103 Qc101 Qc102 Qc103
# 1    NA    NA    NA     3    NA     8    NA    10    NA
# 2    NA    NA    NA     2     3     9    NA    NA    NA
# 3    NA     9    NA    NA    NA     1     4    NA    NA
```

---

##### Solution

You can `pivot_longer()` on groups of columns, and then `summarise()` to keep the only non-missing value by their row IDs.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(matches("Q[abc]"),
               names_to = c(NA, ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)") %>%
  summarise(across(`101`:`103`, ~ .x[!is.na(.x)][1], .names = "Q{.col}"),
            .by = ID)

#      ID  Q101  Q102  Q103
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     3    10     8
# 2     2     2     3     9
# 3     3     4     9     1
```